# AngularJS and php array data

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I recently started learning AngularJS. When I getting data from the database an array, I using function foreach, so my code is

```
<ul>
     <?php foreach($Items as $Item):?>
          <li><?php echo $Item['name'];?></li>
     <?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

I use AngularJS because I need sortable list elements. And my code with AngularJS roughly the

```
<script>
     function PositionsList($scope){
         $scope.positions=<?php echo json_encode($Items);?>
     }
</script>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="position in positions | filter:query">
       <p>{{position.name}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to do so? If not, how to get the data received from server, If not use $http.post/get?

Comment: My initial feeling is that you won't be able to combine ng-repeat and php forEach in this way.

Comment: Does your code not work? That code looks good to me. Could you show the JSON output of the json_encode?

Comment: I think is better not to mix PHP an JS code in the same file. Why do not use AJAX to retrieve the Items array instead of echoing it with PHP?

Comment: MaxPRafferty, This code works, but I'm not sure what I'm doing this right, because the documentation says that the model should be in a separate file, then maybe I'll be send data via ajax

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [ng-init](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInit) to keep your model in a separate file:

```
<ul ng-init="positions = <?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($Items)); ?>">
    <li ng-repeat="position in positions | filter:query">
       <p>{{position.name}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's important to remember that **ng-init** needs to be placed in a parent element level of the **ng-repeat** directive, exactly like is here. 

i was trying to put it in the same element and getting no success

Comment: Another point: there's no sorting of objects in javascript. You need to use an array for sorting in javascript. So when using json_encode the array order may be affected. And inside your `ng-repeat` the order may not match the one in original array.