# ng-init angular parse error including php input in JSON format

Tags: php, angularjs, arrays, json

So I have a php var named $output which when done echo json_encode($output) prints like following:

```
[{
    "title": null
}, {
    "title": "a b c"
}, {
    "title": "d e f"
}, {
    "title": "d f g"
}, {
    "title": "f g d"
}]
```

WHICH I BELIEVE IS CORRECT JSON

now I am using that output to load results via ng-init as it has to be on the same page so I use following code:

```
> <table ng-init="values =<?php echo json_encode($output); ?>">
>      <tr ng-repeat="value in values">
>          <td>{{value}}</td>
>      </tr>  </table>
```

it gives error as follows:

> Error: [$parse:ueoe] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$parse/ueoe?p0=values%20%3D%5B%7B

```
<table ng-init="values =[{" title":null},{"title":"a="" b="" c"}]">
```

***and so on its a big array with lot of words in int. USING ABC IN PLACE OF ORIGNAL WORDS***

Comment: you can't add php code to `html`, and when you add this inside angular directive (`ng-init`), it gives you parse error. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312316/how-do-i-add-php-code-file-to-html-html-files)

Comment: @anoop yes I can its a .phtml extension file

Comment: can you reproduce your error\issue on any online editor for .phtml?

Answer (score 0):

try it:`<table ng-init="values =[{\' title\':null},{\'title\':\'a=\"\" b=\"\" c\'}]">`

Comment: <table ng-init="values =<?php echo json_encode($output); ?>"> IS the code Ebubekir How can I change it manually

Answer (score 0):

You need to get data from your server with call `$http`. After your call, set variable from your `$scope` of your controller and use `ng-repeat` in this variable for display the result.

Comment: that is the case when we make request to a php file but here in this can I have php code and html on same page

Comment: Question is how to make sure that JSON is read correctly by angular or parsed correctly

Comment: Yes but you can't set variable angular from your $scope directly in html file or phtml file or cshtml, ... You need to use call $http for this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17725595/angularjs-and-php-array-data

Comment: ng-init is reading the value but not correctly. Its not an issue of making $http requests

Comment: yeah I know but I am working on magento site anit uses .phtml files to display the products

Answer (score 0):

I found this working somehow.....I dont know how but might help someone

```
 var obj = <?php echo json_encode($output) ?>;
      app.controller('MaCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.obj = $window.obj;

  $scope.getMember = function(id) {
    $scope.values = $scope.obj;
    console.log($scope.values);
  };
}]);

 <table ng-controller="MaCtrl" ng-init="getMember(id)">
     <tr ng-repeat="value in values">
         <td>{{value.title}}</td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```